# jquery ui and asp.net master pages

Tags: jquery, asp.net, user-interface

Can someone please tell me why this code that works without a master page refuses to work when I use nested master pages. The necessary jquery js files have been referenced in the base master page

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Detail.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeBehind="FieldWorkerDetail.aspx.cs" Inherits="FoodVault.Web.WebForms.Admin.FieldWorkerDetail" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="RepeaterPager" Namespace="RepeaterPager" TagPrefix="fv" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>    


<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="LeftContent" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
<script type="text/javascript">     // a workaround for a flaw in the demo system (http://dev.jqueryui.com/ticket/4375), ignore!
    function Show()
     {

            $("#dialog-message").dialog({
                modal: true,
                buttons: {
                    Ok: function () {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    }
                }
            });
            $("#dialog-message").dialog("open");

        }
    </script>
        <div class="demo">
            <input id="Button1" type="button" value="button" onclick="Show()" />
<div id="dialog-message" title="Download complete">
    <p>
        <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-check" style="float:left; margin:0 7px 50px 0;"></span>
        Your files have downloaded successfully into the My Downloads folder.
    </p>
    <p>
        Currently using <b>36% of your storage space</b>.
    </p>
</div>

<!-- Sample page content to illustrate the layering of the dialog -->
<div class="hiddenInViewSource" style="padding:20px;">
    <p>Sed vel diam id libero <a href="http://example.com">rutrum convallis</a>. Donec aliquet leo vel magna. Phasellus rhoncus faucibus ante. Etiam bibendum, enim faucibus aliquet rhoncus, arcu felis ultricies neque, sit amet auctor elit eros a lectus.</p>
    <form>
        <input value="text input" /><br />
        <input type="checkbox" />checkbox<br />
        <input type="submit" onclick="Show()" />radio<br />
        <select>
            <option>select</option>
        </select><br /><br />
        <textarea>textarea</textarea><br />
    </form>
</div><!-- End sample page content -->

</div><!-- End demo -->
```

Comment: Could you provide more detail about what specifically is erroring... Don't make us guess :-)

Comment: Also please add a sample from your masterpage on how you are referencing the libraries

Comment: Is it something silly like having a Show() function in your masterpage?

Answer (score 2):

Check how you are referencing the libraries. Are they local or are you loading them from a CDN? I'd use Google's CDN

```
<script type="text/javascript"  src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"  src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.15/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Here's why you should use a CDN: http://encosia.com/2008/12/10/3-reasons-why-you-should-let-google-host-jquery-for-you/

And another good article on Master Pages in general:
http://odetocode.com/Articles/450.aspx

Seeing you are using local references see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4330380/jquery-with-masterpage-in-asp-net) to ensure the libraries are referenced correctly.

Comment: I have have tried your suggestion, but I am still having no luck.